# Android Studio created a second "first fragment" on an older API version (21), which should i use?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

Im new to Android Studio and just created my first GUI. To make ImageViews lay above buttons i changed the elevation. The programm told me elevation was added on API version 21 (lollipop) and thus created a second "first fragment" with API v21, i use API v30 in my Project. Im confused now. which Fragment should i use? Why is my v30 fragment not able to use elevation? Shall i delete one of them? Is Android Studio using both at the same time to build my API? I did research and found no website able to clear my confusion and questions. I mean, it works but not understanding it wont help me.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Android Studio uses both of them as the UI for your application, one for mobile devices with android version higher than 21 (which is the main layout) and the other for 21 or less which is the layout indicated by (v21). To clear your confusion, some attributes were not available in older versions and so is for the newer versions, as they are new attributes that weren't available back then.

Comment: Well, okay. If i do any Graphical / GUI change in the "main" (v30) fragment they dont happen in the v21. I guess to make it run on older versions i would have to do the same GUI work twice? Which luckily isnt a problem since its only supposed to run on updated devices. Thanks for your answer nonetheless, i'll proceed with working with the v30 fragment only.